# Concluded + name of the person for a press release

Tags: grammar

I am reading a piece.

1- there is a direct quote, that ends with ", concluded Mr. Smith". So it is the following: "there are issues we need to fix", concluded Mr. Smith.

Is that grammatically correct? Shouldn't it be Mr. Smith concluded?

2-There is also another section where the author says, "Representing the UN in the meeting with the ambassador were Mr. Smith and Ms. Linda". Is that a correct formulation?

Comment: "Your conclusion is out of order," concluded Tom.  [That's a Swiftie, if you are too old to remember.]  Both orders are widely used.  Since you do not know that, I conclude that English is not your native language; may I suggest you try our sister forum https://ell.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: You can't *conclude* a word any more than you can *jump* a word or *shrug* a word.  So the speech tag itself is wrong, no matter how it's phrased.

Comment: @JasonBassford "What is the noun form of *conclude*?" "'*Conclusion*', he concluded."

Comment: @Chappo That's exactly my point. You can *shout*, "Conclusion!", *say*, "conclusion", *whisper*, "conclusion," and *mutter*, "conclusion." But you cannot *jump*, "conclusion," *shrug*, "conclusion," or *conclude*, "conclusion." You can, however, conclude that there is a conclusion.

Comment: See ["Use and Misuse of Dialogue Tags."](https://theeditorsblog.net/2010/12/25/use-and-misuse-of-dialogue-tags/)

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm a professional writer, and in my opinion the blog you linked to isn't worth reading. The idea that *“It’s true,” he smiled* is wrong (because you can't "smile" words) reveals the blogger's very limited understanding of writing technique: they would be very quickly corrected on our other site [writing.se]! Bottom line: if you can conclude something, you can put that something in quotation marks and write *"[the concluded thing]", he concluded*. Standard, common, accepted and correct usage.

Comment: @Chappo I can link to many other such writers (and grammarians) with the same opinion. Not only about the generally recognized use of minimal dialogue tags in general but the semantics behind their use. Of course, you're free to write however you like. Especially if you're writing poetry or some other genre where such conventions are laxer.

Comment: @JasonBassford A quick flick through the opening pages of half a dozen prize-winning novels suggests that editors seem to ignore the blogger's advice on "Verbs to never use as tags". [As an aside: her split infinitive suggests she is no grammar purist!] Nonetheless, her blog offers an interesting perspective from within the publishing industry, so I'll post a question on [Writing.se] to see what the writing community's views are.

Answer (score 1):

Attribution of quotes uses both forms: the verb before or after the speaker --

"Quote," said Bob.

"Quote," Bob said.

"Quote?" asked Bob.

"Quote?" Bob asked.

The only one that is uncommon is following the verb with a pronoun:

"Quote," he said. (But not, 'said he.')

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the speech-tag issue, which is contentious in the writing community, your sentence is fine.

(You'll find hundereds of blogs with people ranting about things like how you can't smile "come here" in expressions such as "'come here my darling', he smiled" -- I'll see if I can find some links later. But even if you agree with the speech-tag-phobics, I think it can be argued that "Mr Smith concluded 'there are issues we need to fix' is still ok.)

Your first sentence uses [quotative inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English#Quotative_inversion)

> **Quotative inversion**
>
> In literature, subject-verb inversion occurs with verbs of speaking.
>   The speech being reported is produced in its direct form, usually with
>   quotation marks:
>
> ```
>     a. "We are going to win", Bill said.
>     b. "We are going to win", said Bill. - Quotative inversion
>     c. ?"We are going to win", said he. - Quotative inversion less likely with weak subject pronoun
>
>     a. "What was the problem?", Larry asked.
>     b. "What was the problem?", asked Larry. - Quotative inversion
>     c. ?"What was the problem?", asked he. - Quotative inversion less likely with weak subject pronoun
> ```
>
> This sort of inversion is absent from everyday speech. It occurs
>   almost exclusively in literary contexts.

Your second sentence is also correct. The verb phrase introduced by the gerund "representing" is used as a noun phrase -- "representing the United Nations in the meeting with the ambassador" -- and the verb phrase is then "were Mr Smith and Mrs Linda".